# Case-sensitive filtering of an array of nested pscustomobjects

Tags: powershell

I need help debugging the following sample code I've created to mimic a real scenario in which the $objects pscustomobject array is filtered based on a **case sensitive** match of a nested pscustomobject property against the values stored in $filterTags.

```
# Filtering on the following strings. ***Must match case***
$filterTags = @("application","environment")

$objects = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Object1"; tags = [PSCustomObject]@{ "Application" = "App1"; Environment = "Env1" }},
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Object2"; tags = [PSCustomObject]@{ "Application" = "App2"; environment = "Env2" }},
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Object3"; tags = [PSCustomObject]@{ "application" = "App3"; Environment = "Env3" }},
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Object4"; tags = [PSCustomObject]@{ "Migrate Project" = "Migration1"}}
)

$objects | Where-Object {
     $tagsNames = $_.tags.PSObject.Properties.Name
     $filterTags | ForEach-Object { $tagsNames -ceq $_ }
}

Name    tags
----    ----
Object2 @{Application=App2; environment=Env2}
Object3 @{application=App3; Environment=Env3}
Object4 @{Migrate Project=Migration1}
```

I would only expect objects 2 and 3 to be returned by the last statement. Objects 1 and 4 do not match, so it's great object 1 is filtered out, but why is object4 showing up?

When I run the following, I get expected False values as it's one and only tag does not match, so I don't understand why it shows in the code above.

```
# variable set from previous code final loop
$tagsNames
Migrate Project

$myTags | ForEach-Object { $tagsNames -ceq $_ }
False
False
```

I've tried the following, using ccontains, and it leaves out object 4, but returns objects 1, 2, and 3.

```
$objects | Where-Object {
   $_.tags.PSObject.Properties.Name | % {$myTags -ccontains $_ }
}
```

TIA

Comment: This should give you a hint ;) `[bool] ($false, $false)` (this is exactly what is happening for your last object)

Comment: Interesting, why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is because a collection with more than 1 element coerces to `$true`, no matter what their elements are. See [**Converting from collection types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans?view=powershell-7.3#converting-from-collection-types):

> - Single-element collections evaluate to the Boolean value of their one and only element.
> - Collections with more than 1 element are always `$true`.

Your filtering condition should use `Where-Object` or `.Where` instead of `ForEach-Object`. [`.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#where) is better in this case because it has the `First` mode, it's more efficient as it behaves similar to [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0).

```
$objects | Where-Object {
    $tagsNames = $_.tags.PSObject.Properties.Name
    $filterTags.Where({ $tagsNames -ceq $_ }, 'First')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately your code sampe returns 0 results.  With that said I was able to solve the issue.  See my posted solution.

Comment: @MatthewMcDonald not sure what you mean, works fine for me with your sample data: https://i.imgur.com/C5Zw9tL.png but if you think your answer is better then go with it

Comment: I realized what happened.  I was using a different variable from what I posted and what you used (filterTags).

Comment: Trying to shorten your code a bit but it's not working.  Any ideas why this wouldn't work:

$objects | Where-Object -PipelineVariable obj {
$myTags.Where({ $obj.tags.PSObject.Properties.Name -ceq $_ }, 'First')
 }

Comment: @MatthewMcDonald `-PipelineVariable` is "the variable name for the next command in the pipeline", i.e.: `1..10 | Where-Object -PV i { $_ } | ForEach-Object { $i }`

Comment: I figured that may be the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I found a solution using cmatch.

```
$objects | Where-Object {
      $_.tags.PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object {$myTags -cmatch $_ }
}

Name    tags
----    ----
Object2 @{Application=App2; environment=Env2}
Object3 @{application=App3; Environment=Env3}
```